# Confusing Laravel Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

can someone explain this laravel validation

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'
```

What's the purpose of `NULL, id` in it?

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320281/laravel-validation-unique-rule-4th-parameter

Comment: Check the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#available-validation-rules) !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel validation: unique rule 4th parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320281/laravel-validation-unique-rule-4th-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Basic Usage Of Unique Rule

```
'email' => 'unique:users'
```

Specifying A Custom Column Name

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address'
```

Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,10'
```

Adding Additional Where Clauses

You may also specify more conditions that will be added as "where" clauses to the query:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'
```

In the rule above, only rows with an account_id of 1 would be included in the unique check.

Documents References (i.e. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation)